# Does GPT-3 remember data from prompts used to fine tune it?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tokenization, gpt, finetuning

I am trying to fine tune a model using OpenAI's fine tuning API. I am passing bodies of text (for example, news paper articles) as prompts and the data I want from it as completions.

Let us consider the following: if a newspaper article I passed as a prompt to fine tune the data, consists of some information that GPT did not know before, like 'lithium ores are found in India'. If I use the completion API after that to ask GPT 'are lithium ores found in India?' as a prompt, will GPT be able to answer 'yes'?

Answer (score 0):

> Does GPT-3 remember data from prompts used to fine tune it?

Very unlikely, according the [LIMA: Less Is More for Alignment](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.11206) paper:

> These results strongly suggest that **almost all knowledge in large language models is learned during pretraining**, and only limited instruction tuning data is necessary to teach models to produce high quality output.

Also note that labels in prompts don't seem to matter much, see [Rethinking the Role of Demonstrations: What Makes In-Context Learning Work?](https://aclanthology.org/2022.emnlp-main.759.pdf).[Sewon Min](https://aclanthology.org/people/s/sewon-min/), [Xinxi Lyu](https://aclanthology.org/people/x/xinxi-lyu/), [Ari Holtzman](https://aclanthology.org/people/a/ari-holtzman/), [Mikel Artetxe](https://aclanthology.org/people/m/mikel-artetxe/), [Mike Lewis](https://aclanthology.org/people/m/mike-lewis/), [Hannaneh Hajishirzi](https://aclanthology.org/people/h/hannaneh-hajishirzi/), [Luke Zettlemoyer](https://aclanthology.org/people/l/luke-zettlemoyer/). EMNLP 2022.